# Converting string to date with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdateformatter

Im trying to convert this string '2015-05-08T09:44:25.343' format to date 'dd/MM/YYYY' format

What I`m doing wrong? my date comes Nil.

```
// convert 2015-05-08T09:44:25.343 to dd/MM/yyyy

NSString *str = @"2015-05-08T09:44:25.343";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];

NSLog(@"%@",date);        
NSString *convertedString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]; 
NSLog(@"%@", convertedString);
```

Comment: How does `str` match the format you gave?

Comment: @Larme I have this format: 2015-05-08T09:44:25.343 and I want this format: dd/MM/yyyy. for some reasons the date comes Nil to me...

Comment: Did you do some research? How can `NSDateFormatter` understand the format of `str`? You have to give it the format. Then you transform it to a `NSDate`. Once it's done, you change the format to whatever you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"2015-05-08T09:44:25.343";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"];// this string must match given string @"2015-05-08T09:44:25.343"

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];

NSLog(@"%@",date);
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];// this match the one you want to be        
NSString *convertedString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]; 
NSLog(@"%@", convertedString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format string does not match up with the format of the date you provided. Try this.

```
NSString *str = @"2015-05-08T09:44:25.343";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
```

Then you can convert as needed.